# Cannot use a "." in a Hive table column name

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, emr

I'm using Hive `2.1.1` and I'm attempting to create a table with `.` in a column name:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table`(
  `field.with.dots` string
);
```

When I do so I get:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 Failed to recognize predicate ')'. Failed rule: '[., :] can not be used in column name in create table statement.' in column specification
```

I must be doing something wrong because the [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/Partition/Column) says:

> In Hive release 0.13.0 and later, by default column names can be specified within backticks (`) and contain any Unicode character (HIVE-6013)

`.` is a unicode character. And idea what I might be doing?

To give you more context this is on an Amazon EMR 5.5.0 cluster. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source code: [HiveParser](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/HiveParser.g)

```
...
private char [] excludedCharForColumnName = {'.', ':'};
...

  private CommonTree throwColumnNameException() throws RecognitionException {
    throw new FailedPredicateException(input, Arrays.toString(excludedCharForColumnName) + " can not be used in column name in create table statement.", "");
  }
```

---

Jira ticket :[Disallow create table with dot/colon in column name](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10120)

Please note the motivation:

> Since we don't allow users to query column names with dot in the
>   middle such as emp.no, don't allow users to create tables with such
>   columns that cannot be queried

It seems `create table` was handled, but not `CTAS` nor ALTER TABLE...

```
hive> create table t as select 1 as `a.b.c`;
OK
hive> desc t;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
a.b.c                   int                                         
Time taken: 0.441 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from t;
FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field a from [0:a.b.c]
```

---

```
hive> create table t (i int);
OK
hive> alter table t change column i `a.b.c` int
hive> select * from t;
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field a from [0:a.b.c]
```

**P.s.**

**I have updated the documentation** (look for `colon`)
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Comment: Thanks, I have that enabled, and unfortunately it doesn't resolve the issue :(

Comment: P.s. For the fun of it try using a comma (`,`) in a column name, e.g. `\`a,b,c\``

Comment: Yep it works. Thanks for your help. It's a bummer because we have a schema that is created from JSON documents. Dot notation is pretty common there. I'm not sure why Hive cares if the column name is quoted.

Comment: `create table t (\`a,b,c\` int);` works for you? I'm getting `"FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe: columns has 3 elements while columns.types has 1 elements!)"`